# Hangman: Reverse Edition

Tags: wordplay, language, english

> Put a P, then Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva will turn a goddess into this.
>
> Put an R, you speak it more than writing it.
>
> Put a T, I become e-learning.
>
> Put a G, then I become a floor.

If you're new to reverse hangman:

> The final answer will be a string with one letter blank which can be filled in in several different ways to form a valid word (eg "_it" can make lit, fit, kit, bit, etc.)

In your answer, please give the string with the missing letter and explain each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> O_AL

Put a P, then Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva will turn a goddess into this.

> OPAL
>  As far as I can tell, in Indian mythology, the Virgin Goddess of the Rainbow was turned into an opal by the Mother Goddess because Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva were pursuing her.

Put an R, you speak it more than writing it.

> ORAL

Put a T, I become e-learning.

> [OTAL](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/OTAL)
>  Online Teaching and Learning at the University of Maryland

Put a G, then I become a floor.

> OGAL
>  Not totally certain about this one but there is [this Urban Dictionary reference](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ogal) which specifically references a floor. Also, the [Ogallala Aquifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogallala_Aquifer) is a shallow water table aquifer surrounded by sand, silt, clay, and gravel located beneath the Great Plains in the United States. I think this also maybe can be shortened to "Ogal".